# Math and social commitment

Tags: soft-question, mathematics-education

I am a master's student and am looking for ways that link a certain social commitment with **serious** math. Since I have not found such an overview yet and in order to raise public awareness of such opportunities, I decided to pose this question (feel free to put this question on hold, if you feel that it violates any of your rules).

Recently, a friend told me that he will work as a TA at the African Institute for Mathematical Sciences. I just saw that more senior mathematicians can go to these institutes as lecturers.

In this sense, I am looking for similar opportunities where people can use part of their free-time to do serious mathematics in developing countries on a rather voluntary basis. Are there similar slots available somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this should be a comment, but it sounds like you might want to look into the activities of the IMU's [Commision for Developing Countries.](http://www.mathunion.org/cdc/)  In particular, see their [Volunteer Lecturer Program](http://www.mathunion.org/cdc/volunteer-lecturer-program/information-and-registration-for-lecturers/).

Answer (score 0):

You can volunteer with [datakind](http://datakind.org), which helps social change organizations with data science.  That is an opportunity to use serious statistics and any other relevant math.